# How to show a message by an if-statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an `index.html` and inside this file, I wrote code in order to show a message which is "hello" here. My goal is to implement code that shows three types of message: "Good morning", "Good evening", and "Good night".

Follows my code:

```
<p id="show_time" class="time"></p>
<script>
window.onload = show_time('show_time');

    function show_time(id) {
      h = date.getHours();

      if h == 22 {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "hello";
      }
      setTimeout('show_time("' + id + '");','1000');
      return true;
   }
}
```

In this code I only wrote one case. The class, time, is a `css` property that contains font-size and font-family. The `h` gets present hour and if `h` is 22 , "hello" is going to be output. But this does not work.

It is so helpful if you could provide code that displays the three types of message.

Thank you

Comment: `h>0&&h<=16` show("Good morning"). `h>16&&h<=20` show("Good evening"). `h>20&&h<=24` show("Good night"). Something like this?

Comment: write if in parantheses. 'if (h==22){ //your code}'

Comment: if (h == 22) { will work

Comment: declare variable using `var h`

Comment: You have a lot of syntax errors. For example `window.onload = show_time('show_time');` should be `window.onload = show_time.bind(this, "show_time");`. And `setTimeout('show_time("' + id + '");','1000');`, `setTimeot(show_time.bind(this, id),1000);`. And the others that have been mentioned already.

Comment: I tried several code that you guys gave me but somehow did not work, but  I solved this problem by code that @ZoltanToth provided!! Thanks everyone!! My English is bad but I appreciate you guys helped me with this!! Again thanks!!

Comment: This line is also incorrect: h = date.getHours();
Change to var h = new Date().getHours(); And for some reason this returns null: document.getElementById(id)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var h = new Date().getHours(),
      msg = 'morning';
  
  if (h > 12) { msg = 'afternoon'; } 
  if (h > 20) { msg = 'night'; }

  document.getElementById('show_time').innerHTML = msg;
}
```

```html
<p id="show_time" class="time"></p>
```

Comment: I wondered if I could change msg color by style inside the brackets. Like this; { msg = 'afternood'; msg.style.color = 'orange'; } This code did not work so if you know its helpful too. Thanks

Comment: you have to change the style of the `#show_time` element, not the msg

Answer (score 0):

Like this??

```js
/* next line if false, see the comments on this answer!!! */
window.onload = show_time('show_time');

function show_time(id) {
  var date = new Date(),
      h = date.getHours();

  if( h > 0 && h < 6 ) {
    var msg = "Good night";
  }
  else if( h >= 6 && h < 12 ) {
    var msg = "Good morning";
  }
  else if( h >= 12 && h < 18 ) {
    var msg = "Good day";
  }
  else if( h >= 18 && h < 24 ) {
    var msg = "Good evening";
  }
  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = msg;
  setTimeout('show_time("' + id + '");', '1000');
}
```

```html
<p id="show_time" class="time"></p>
```

Comment: `window.onload = show_time('show_time');` doesn't look good, `window.onload` needs a reference to a function.

Comment: @Titus, check the second example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: I've checked it. It is `load` not `load()`, is a reference to a function, not the result of running the function. It should be `window.onload = show_time` or `window.onload = show_time.bind(this, 'show_time');` to pass the argument as well.

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll leave my answer unedited, so others can learn from it.